# how to remove item from list and update list in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

i have platform list in my project , i want remove one item from platform list and see update list without reloading
platform list image : [platform list image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVnUr.jpg)

i use ui-route in my project

body of platform-list.html :

```
<tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="platform in platforms">
            <td>{{platform.PlatformID}}</td>
            <td>{{platform.Name}}</td>
            <td><button ui-sref="platform-edit({id: platform.PlatformID})" class="btn btn-warning">Edit&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
            <button ng-click="remove(platform.PlatformID)"  class="btn btn-danger">Delete&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

platform-list-controller.js :

```
mainApp.controller('platformListController', function ($scope, platform, $filter) {
  platform.query().$promise.then(function (data) {
    $scope.platforms = data;
  }, function (error) {
  });    
});
```

platform model :

```
public class Platform
{        
    [Key]
    public int PlatformID { get; set; }    
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

how to write remove code in this controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code solve your problem :

```
mainApp.controller('platformListController', function ($scope, platform, $filter) {    
platform.query().$promise.then(function (data) {
    $scope.platforms = data;
}, function (error) {
});

//add this code 
$scope.remove = function (id) {
    platform.remove({ id: id }).$promise.then(function () {
        $scope.platforms = $filter('filter')($scope.platforms, function (item) {
            return item.PlatformID !== id;
        });
        alert('Removed');
    }, function (error) {
        alert('Failed');
    });
};
//

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array.splice()` method to remove data from array. This syntex is

```
array.splice(index , howMany[, element1[, ...[, elementN]]])
```

In your controller

```
mainApp.controller('platformListController', function ($scope, platform, $filter) {

  $scope.platforms = [];

  platform.query().$promise.then(function (data) {
    $scope.platforms = data;
  }, function (error) {
  });

$scope.remove = function(platformId, index){
    $scope.platforms.splice(index,1);
}

});
```

and your html should be like following:

```
<tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="platform in platforms">
            <td>{{platform.PlatformID}}</td>
            <td>{{platform.Name}}</td>
            <td><button ui-sref="platform-edit({id: platform.PlatformID})" class="btn btn-warning">Edit&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
            <button ng-click="remove(platform.PlatformID, $index)"  class="btn btn-danger">Delete&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

What are the properties of `$scope.platforms`? Probably the easiest (not the most efficient) is to add an `ng-click` attribute.

In terms of code, this would be the HTML for the Delete button:

```
`<btn ng-model="delBtn" ng-click="deletePlatform(platform.id)">
    <span>Delete</span>
</btn>`
```

and the function in the controller or directive would be:

```
`function deletePlatform(platform.id) {
    $scope.platforms.filter(function (platformItem) {
        return platformItem.id !== platform.id;
    });
}`
```